# jQuery: I cannot modify an element's CSS color after using append()

Tags: jquery

I have used jQuery's append() command to create a set of DIVs from an array.

After doing a simple JSON request, I would now like to change the color of the text within the DIV using the css() command. However, I cannot seem to get it to work.

Here is a cross-section of the code I have written:

```
function createList(myArray){
    $.each(myArray,function(index,item){
        $("#results_panel").append('<div id="result_'+item+'">'+item+'</div>');
        doSomeStuff(item);
    });
}

function doSomeStuff(item){
    var urlJSON="file_upload.php?ip_address="+item;
    $.getJSON(urlJSON,function(json){
        if (json.result == "true") {
            $("#result_"+item).css("color","#00FF00");
        } else {
            $("#result_"+item).css("color","#FF0000");
        }
    });
}
```

If I use document.getElementByID.("result_"+item).style.color this will work, however.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here? I'm fairly new to jQuery, so apologies if this is a really obvious question.

Comment: Is your getJSON erroring out?

Comment: The getJSON returns successfully. I can do an alert that pops up with the expected value.

Comment: There must be something outside of this code that is causing problems.  All I have done is change the url and how the data is passed, and it seems to me to be working: http://jsfiddle.net/Ender/NVngU/1/

Comment: This probably doesn't have anything to do with your problem, but I did notice that inside `doSomeStuff()` you are declaring a `url` var, but when you make the `$.getJSON()` call, you are passing it a variable called `urlJSON`.

Comment: Is your if statement returning actual "true"/"false" as strings or is it returning a true/false boolean value?

Comment: @Ender, I mistyped the url variable when I was entering the code into StackOverflow. I've updated the code in the question now to reflect what it should've been!

Comment: @Ender - you must be right since your example seems to work just fine. It's odd though, that I can replace the jQuery css() with document.getElementByID.("result_"+item).style.color and it works...

Comment: @DA - it is returning "true/false" as strings, not boolean. It's just for testing at the moment. I plan to replace them with some other info once I get this working.

Comment: I've found the problem/solution (I think). Have a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is the values that you are using as the ID of your elements.  [Have a look at this fiddle ->](http://jsfiddle.net/Ender/uzHTB/)

The DOM method will allow a name with an IP in it.  jQuery, however, interprets the `.`s in the IP address as the beginning of a class selector, and thus does not select anything.

Have a look at these two demos:

- [This is the same demo I posted in your question comments, but with IP values ->](http://jsfiddle.net/Ender/NVngU/3/)
- [IP values, dots replaced with underscores ->](http://jsfiddle.net/Ender/NVngU/2/)

By replacing the `.`s in the IP with underscores, the ID becomes valid for jQuery selection, and the color will be correctly applied.

Comment: Pretty cool how you noticed that just by looking at the json url :) voted up

Comment: @dakis - Believe me, it was blind luck that I finally saw it, but thank you nonetheless :)

Comment: this was the problem! Thank you very much for helping me with this. I really appreciate it :)

Comment: @durzagott - Happy to be of assistance :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm attempting to answer a question with an answer that may be completely wrong. I'll let the downvoting forces correct me if I am wrong. ;o)

The issue (I believe) is that your elements aren't appended until the array is finished cycling. So they're not in the DOM yet to be selected. One fix would be to move the CSS updates into the loop itself: create a new jQuery div element, apply the CSS, THEN append it.

Comment: The thing is, I'd like to show the div first. When the JSON response comes in (it's a file upload) then I'd like to turn the color green or red, depending on success. I'll give it a shot though.

Comment: I don't think that's it.  Have a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ender/NVngU/

Comment: @ender I believe you are correct! I totally missed that he was using jQuery's each, which I do not thing has that issue.

Comment: Huh. Apparently, you can't downvote your own answer. SOMEONE DOWNVOTE ME! ;)

Comment: @DA - Lol!  You can delete it if you're really concerned, but I think it's fine, as an indication of what has been tried :)

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle, Ender. At least it shows that in theory it should work. I guess somewhere in the getJSON things are getting lost.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve **two problems**--the one you mention and the one you may not realize is resulting from appending code within the .each call--with a slightly different approach where you create all the HTML, then append it in one shot.  This approach will make the problem you are experiencing moot, plus it will provide much better performance.

See http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/02/5-easy-tips-on-how-to-improve-code.html  or http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/03/43439-reasons-to-use-append-correctly for a detailed example of what I am referring to.

Comment: Thank you for the links. I've followed the advice and adjusted my code to do the append() after building up all the HTML. Although I will continue doing this from now on, I'm afraid it hasn't made any  difference to the outcome of the problem.